# How to cancel a space between separate table cells

Tags: html, html-table, border-spacing

I've made a table with border-spacing of 16px height and I want to cancel that space only for one specific cell.
Here's the table:

```html
<table width="100%" style="text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 16px;">
  <tr style="background-image: url(Pics/background.jpg);">
    <td> Some text </td>
  </tr>
<!--Only here I do not want a space-->
  <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0 0;">
    <td> Text </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to keep the space for the rest of the table, hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!!
I've simply positioned the row I wanted to have no space with the row on top of it higher 'till the space between them was gone. 
The code I've used:

```html
<td style="position: relative; bottom: 18px;>
```

Simple as that.. xD